# Rooted Android streaming video client for local ip camera without any delays

Tags: android, root, rtsp, ip-camera

I have an ip camera and I want to include the video stream in an Android activity. To do that I included a VideoLayout with id *video* and I added this code to the onCreate method in the Activity.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.225/axis-media/media.amp");
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    }
```

It works but there is an annoying delay of 10 seconds between the acquisition of the image from the camera and the displaying to the phone. I want the delay lesser than 2 seconds. I know the problem is related the fixed size of the buffer used for caching images during RTSP session. If I use vlc I can view the stream well by setting *network-caching=0*. Is there a way to do that in Android? The software destination is a ROOTED  Android 4.0.3. Can I resolve by taking advantage of the root? I read that I can set the media.stagefright.cache-params of the build.prop file but I don't know if it is useful and how to set it.. 
Please help me! Thank you!